# how can I disable landscape mode javafx?

Tags: android, ios, javafx, landscape, gluon

I want to disable landscape modeon javafx app for the whole app. How can I do that?
I'm also using Gluon plugin.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

On Android by default you have enabled changes between portrait and landscape orientations.

If you want just portrait orientation, you can set this on the `AndroidManifest.xml` file under src/android/:

```
<activity android:name="javafxports.android.FXActivity" 
                      android:label="<yourAppName>" 
                      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                      android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
    ...
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your AndroidManifest.xml under the activity tag:

```
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```